# Cannot disable key with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard has a stuck **end** key (which is also **numpad 1**). I tried disabling it with the command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 87 = '
```

I also tried:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 87 = 0x0000'
```

I checked `xmodmap -pke` and `xev` and keycode 87 is the correct one for this key.

After running these commands, the effects of the stuck key stop temporarily, but eventually come back.

For example pages scroll to the end, etc. Also, `xev` shows events for keycode 87.

Is there a way to stop the end key from being triggered at all? Is `xmodmap` the only way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the keyboard is unplugged; there's no way to do this with xmodmap, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623818/xmodmap-resets-when-keyboard-mode-changes.